# Is it possible to invoke private attributes or methods via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to fetch the value of an static private attribute via reflection, but it fails with an error.

```
Class class = home.Student.class;
Field field = studentClass.getDeclaredField("nstance");
Object obj = field.get(null);
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.test.ReflectionTest can not access a member of class home.Student with modifiers "private static".
```

Moreover, there is a private I need to invoke, with the following code.

```
Method method = studentClass.getMethod("addMarks");
method.invoke(studentClass.newInstance(), 1);
```

but the problem is the Student class is a singleton class, and constructor in private, and cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can set the field accessible:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 22):

Yes it is. You have to set them accessible using [`setAccessible(true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) defined in [AccesibleObject](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html) that is a super class of both [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) and [`Method`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

With the static field you should be able to do:

```
Class class = home.Student.class;
Field field = studentClass.getDeclaredField("nstance");
field.setAccessible(true); // suppress Java access checking
Object obj = field.get(null); // as the field is a static field  
                              // the instance parameter is ignored 
                              // and may be null. 
field.setAccesible(false); // continue to use Java access checking
```

And with the private method

```
Method method = studentClass.getMethod("addMarks");
method.setAccessible(true); // exactly the same as with the field
method.invoke(studentClass.newInstance(), 1);
```

And with a private constructor:

```
Constructor constructor = studentClass.getDeclaredConstructor(param, types);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
constructor.newInstance(param, values);
```

Comment: the constructor is private, and can we still invoke that by using `newInstance` method???

Comment: there is small typo, field.setAccessible(false);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "cheat" like this:

```
    Field somePrivateField = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("somePrivateFieldName");
    somePrivateField.setAccessible(true); // Subvert the declared "private" visibility
    Object fieldValue = somePrivateField.get(someInstance);
```