# how to mock autowire fields using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Here I am trying to mock autowire fields **ServiceHelper** of Service class **TestServiceImpl** , I am not able to call method through mock object of **ServiceHelper** class.

This is my class files:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestDAO testDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;

    @Override
    public ResultsModel getResults(Map<String, Object> map) throws WebServiceException_Exception  {     
        return serviceHelper.getResults(map);
    }
```

2nd Class:

```
@Repository
public class ServiceHelper {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceHelper.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    ResponseHeader responseHeader;

    public void setResponseHeader(ResponseHeader responseHeader) {
        this.responseHeader = responseHeader;
    }

    public ResultsModel getResults(Map<String, Object> map) throws WebServiceException_Exception {
        ....
        }
```

And Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTester {

    @InjectMocks
    private TestServiceImpl serviceImpl = new TestServiceImpl();

    @Mock
    private TestDAO testDAO;

    @Mock
    private ServiceHelper sHelper;

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testResult() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("TestId", "test123");
        map.put("lang", "en");
        map.put("cntry", "USA");
        ResultsModel results = new ResultsModel();

        when(sHelper.getResults(map)).thenReturn(results);
        results = serviceImpl.getResults(map);

        Assert.assertEquals(results.getStatus(), "Success");
    }
```

Here in my test class:

```
results = serviceImpl.getResults(map); 

It goes to TestServiceImpl class to method :

public ResultsModel getResults(Map<String, Object> map) throws webServiceException_Exception  {     
        return serviceHelper.getResults(map);
    }
```

but at point :

```
serviceHelper.getResults(map);
```

it is not going inside `serviceHelper.getResults(map)` and return all values as Null.

```
Please suggest where I need to do changes.
```

Comment: When you paste code, please keep format well. People would like to read well-formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you are stubbing your method to return the same object which you then assign the result of the method under test. i.e. (the `results` object here):

```
ResultsModel results = new ResultsModel();

when(sHelper.getResults(map)).thenReturn(results);
results = serviceImpl.getResults(map);
```

This will probably cause some sort of cyclic confusion when it tries to stub the method in Mockito, and it certainly won't make your assertation pass:

```
Assert.assertEquals(results.getStatus(), "Success");
```

Since the status on results is never set anywhere.

I think you need to make separate objects for your stubbing and your returned value from the method under test and make sure you set your stubbed one to have a status of "Success":

```
ResultsModel results = new ResultsModel();
results.setStatus("Success");
when(sHelper.getResults(map)).thenReturn(results);
ResultsModel returnedResults = serviceImpl.getResults(map);
Assert.assertEquals(returnedResults.getStatus(), "Success");
```

Comment: I did the changes but getting same Null reponse. actually in class TestServiceImpl  method getResults called and it return "return serviceHelper.getResults(map);". here when i debug i found instead of serviceHelper it refer it as sHelper (i.e. @Mock
 private ServiceHelper sHelper; in Test class) and there it failed and return Null

Comment: Oh yes sorry I realise now my change doesn't matter and would have caused a different issue if it did. Bit tired today I apologise. Does your test work if you stub it with a matcher instead of the map? i.e. try this:  `when(sHelper.getResults(Matchers.any(Map.class)).thenReturn(results);`

Comment: multiple values send with Map, so its required. I did not get you what pass her : when(sHelper.getResults(any(Map.class)).thenReturn(results)

Comment: Im not suggesting it as a fix I just want to see if it works. Matchers.any() is a static method provided by the Mockito class Matchers https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html it wil laccept any Map

Comment: getting the same null response .I used below line of code:  when(sHelper.getResults(Matchers.anyMap())).thenReturn(results);

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your previous reply. I'll have a think now

Comment: Hey, its work for me . I set the actual values and add the object to ThenReturn() and after creating new object did the comparison here  assertEquals( , ). Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Accept my answer if it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 8):

You have three choices here:

1. Do actual Spring autowiring in your tests
2. Use injection methods that can legitimately be performed by your tests (constructor parameters, public setters, public fields - in order of preference)
3. Use reflection to inject your mocks

---

Option 1 is really integration testing -- you can annotate your test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and use more Spring annotations to control dependency injection. It's too big a subject to cover in a SO answer, but there are plenty of examples if you Google for "spring integration test mockito".

---

But for unit testing, I think it's better not to involve Spring. A good Spring bean doesn't need Spring to function. Option 2 just says, write your class so that unit tests (and anything else) can inject the dependency (be it a mock, or anything else) through normal Java means.

Constructor injection is cleanest in my opinion:

```
private final ServiceHelper serviceHelper; // note: not annotated

@Autowired
public TestService(ServiceHelper serviceHelper) {
    this.serviceHelper = serviceHelper;
}
```

But you can also do this with a `public void setServiceHelper(ServiceHelper helper)` -- this is less good because the field can't be `final`.

Or by making the field `public` -- I assume you know the reasons this is bad.

---

If you're determined to have a private field that's not set by a public constructor or setter, you could use Spring's `ReflectionUtils.setField()` from within your test:

```
 @Mock
 private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;

 private TestService service;

 @Before
 public void configureService() {
     service = new TestService();
     Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(TestService.class, "serviceHelper");
     ReflectionUtils.setField(field, service, serviceHelper);
 }
```

(Or, equally, use JDK's reflection classes directly, or reflection utils from elsewhere)

This is explicitly using reflection to subvert the access rules you've coded into the class. I thoroughly recommend option 2.

Comment: Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(TestService.class, "serviceHelper");  Here Field of which class java.lang.reflect.Field , please confirm

Comment: In my case the libraries I used were `java.lang.reflect.Field;` and `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;`

Comment: Also this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6911478/8169904 since I was having error modifying the private field. Thanks for this detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using constructor injection it'd be easier to mock the classes for testing... here's an example on how I would structure my classes to get you going. When you write your tests you now have to pass the Mocked object into the instance you're creating of these classes:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
  private TestDao testDao;
  private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;

  @Autowired
  public TestServiceImpl(TestDAO testDAO, ServiceHelper serviceHelper) {
    this.testDAO = testDAO;
    this.serviceHelper = serviceHelper;
  }
}

@Repository
public class ServiceHelper {
  private ResponseHeader responseHeader;

  @Autowired
  public ServiceHelper(ResponseHeader responseHeader) {
    this.responseHeader = responseHeader  
  }
}
```